# how to use an aggregate function on a subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wanted to use `MAX aggregate` function on an EXIST `subquery` but I don't know how to do that(I encountered an error while trying to solve that).
The database is `northwind`, and DBMS is `PostgreSQL`.

What I want from the query:

```
USA 13
```

the query:

```
SELECT max(co) FROM customers
WHERE exists
  (
    SELECT country, count(*) AS co FROM customers 
    WHERE country=customers.country GROUP BY country
  )
```

the error is:

> co does not exist

Comment: Please don’t tag MySQL if it doesn’t relate to this question. As for the error, the subquery doesn’t relate to anything outside it so you’ll have to rewrite it to have the condition you want and then get results from that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT country, COUNT(*) as co
FROM customers
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY co DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

If more than one country has the same maximal COUNT(*) then one random row from these rows will be returned. If you need all of them then use

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT country, COUNT(*) as co
              FROM customers
              GROUP BY country )
SELECT cte.*
FROM cte
WHERE co = ( SELECT MAX(co)
             FROM cte )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dense_rank function

```
select x.country from (
SELECT COUNTRY,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*)) rn
FROM customers) x where rn = 1;
```